# What does this code concerning sys.args mean?

Tags: python, argv, sys

What does the following chunk of code mean? I don't understand the concept of sys.argv. I heard it has something to do with command-line prompts but my vocabulary isn't good enough to understand that. Also the output is strange. I don't understand how a list is pulled up nor how the elements get in there or even where they come from and what they mean. This is really confusing me, so help understanding it would be much appreciated. Please use beinner terms so I can understand it.

```
import sys

print 'Number of arguments:', len(sys.argv), 'arguments.'
print 'Argument List:', str(sys.argv)
```

Comment: [Have you read the doc?](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most programs accept arguments to change how they behave.  e.g.

```
grep some_string myfile.ext
```

This command (on unix systems) looks for `'some_string'` in `myfile.ext` and prints matching lines to the console.

So the question is how does `grep` (the program that is being run), know what to look for, or what file to look in?  The answer is obvious -- It gets passed those arguments via the command line.  You have the power to pass arguments from the commandlint to your python programs too:

```
python my_python_file.py argument1 argument2
```

In this case, if `my_python_file.py` had the contents in your question, `sys.argv` would contain `['my_python_file.py', 'argument1', 'argument2']`

And so you can look in `sys.argv` and see `'argument1'` in there and have your code take certain actions accordingly.  Note that it is fairly uncommon to parse `sys.argv` by hand unless it is a *really* simple case.  Normally, you would use something like `argparse` to parse the arguments for you and give you back the parsed information in a much more easy to manage format.

Answer (score 2):

`sys.argv` is a list of `string`s containing the arguments when the `Python` script was executed (i.e. `>> python main.py arg1 arg2`).

Note that the first argument will always be the name of the command. The first "actual" argument is located in `sys.argv[1]` (assuming at least one argument was passed in).

Comment: Please explain these arguments. What are they? Just file names and type of file? That's what it seems like. I think i'm off though.

Comment: See the answer @mgilson gives